# Gnome3 Install fail on 12.10

Tags: 12.10, gnome

I recently upgraded to 12.10 and found it was running a little slow. My laptop is a few years old and so I accept that the issue is probably my hardware.

When looking online I found it mentioned on many sites that installing Gnome3 would (or should) give me back my speed.

I found a few tutorials on You Tube and they all used the same methods to get the install done.

I followed these and the system worked fine - until I restarted.

I began to lose functions one at a time and now cannot boot back into Ubuntu at all.

I have a Windows 8 dual boot. Windows 8 is still working as well as it was before.

I can boot up ok to the login screen. I can login as a guest and have function - just no access to my files.

When I try to log in as my username I get as far as loading the background and it stops. This is in Unity, Gnome, Gnome Classic and Gnome Classic w/o frills.

What have I done wrong? How do I recover back to the start without losing files?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps, you could 1) provide the specs of your laptop and 2) provide actual links to the videos you followed or at least summarize the steps you took. When you say you *began to lose functions one at a time*, what does that mean. How many days and how many login/logout cycles were involved? When you login as guest,do you have full functionality (other than access to your home folder)?

Comment: Hi,I have an Aspire 4920 laptop with 4Gb ram and Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU T5250 @ 1.50GHz × 2 processor. I can boot into Gnome 3 as Guest but not as my usual user. After the initial install I lost the ability to view video files, followed closely by the loss of access to all files. I now cannot log into my main user account at all.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mYbB_NnIERE

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YTw9e2n25uE - these are the two You Tube videos used as main installation reference. Seemed to be ok as Guest account is working! :)

Comment: Are you sure you're dual booting with Windows 8 and not Windows 7?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's a problem with Ubuntu and Win 8 DualBoot as ist was reported here: http://www.h-online.com/open/features/Linux-and-Windows-8-Fast-Startup-puts-data-at-risk-1780640.html

What happened if you use Unity without Changes for a longer time? Also dataloss?
What happened if you use another Desktop like XFCE?

Comment: I am a newbie to all of this. I am very much a plug and play kinda guy and this stuff does my head in. I too have W8 - and it was working great with 12.04. Personally I have a very strong aversion to Unity and have changed to Gnome for 11.04, 11.10 and 12.04. This is the first failure/issue I have had. It seems to get harder rather than easier every year.

Comment: At the moment I am unable to get back into Unity via the main login. It was running fine and the upgrades were ok. This is very upsetting as I have now lost a week and looks like I will now also lose a massive amount of data. I know all about the backup, backup, backup mantra, but I have done this before ok. Sigh.....

Comment: This is a Problem in 12.10 not in 12.04 or earlier. And it is caused by Win not by Ubuntu. Try to boot a Live-Disk an copy your data on an external HDD or something. Then you are safe. I would recommend to do the Prevention-Task as it is given here http://www.h-online.com/open/features/Linux-and-Windows-8-Fast-Startup-puts-data-at-risk-1780640.html?page=2 and reinstall Ubuntu after that (and after backup) to have a clean system.

Answer (score 0):

My laptop using dual boot too. With win8. but i'm installing ubuntu with fresh install not upgrade, and it works fine. To install Gnome just go to Terminal and type Sudo apt-get install gnome gnome-shell

Comment: Anything I do from here will cause massive data loss. I really do not want that. I am a little grumpy as I have done this for the last three distros without issue. :-)